# Jupyter Notebook is not working on Anaconda Navigator

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g48FF.png)

I'm facing a problem with Anaconda's Jupyter Notebook not launching properly. When I run the 'jupyter notebook' command, it doesn't open as expected, and I'm encountering an issue. Despite my efforts to troubleshoot the problem, I haven't been able to resolve it.

I've taken several steps, including verifying my Anaconda installation, updating Anaconda and its packages, activating the correct Anaconda environment, and checking for any error messages in the terminal. However, the issue persists, and I'm unable to use Jupyter Notebook for my work.